# Как объединить 3 картинки в одну?

Tags: python, opencv

Как объединить 3 картинки в cv2?:

[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

[image: Картинка 3]

В одну?:

[image: Картинка 4]

Comment: А как должна выглядеть одна картинка?

Comment: @Александр https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ilwD.jpg

Comment: @Александр в opencv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14063070/5909792

Comment: Михаил Петров, это слишком просто для OpenCV